# Change the include path for ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, include-path

I am working on a custom library for Flash ActionScript3, and I have a handful of functions that I would like to add to `Array.prototype`.

I placed the extension in a separate `.as` file within a folder in the library directory, but when I make the `include` call from my document class, it tries to execute the include relative to the `.fla` file's location, rather than the library's source path.

I have already added the lib path to the `Source Path:` values under `ActionScript3 Advanced Settings`, which works for my `import` statements.

How do I get the `include` path to be relative to the library's path?

dir structure:

```
flash/
  lib/libname/inc/array.as
  projectname/project.fla
```

include that doesn't work (but should):

```
include "libname/inc/array.as";
```

include that works, but isn't portable if I move the project to a different location:

```
include "../lib/libname/inc/array.as";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a realization about how I was calling the `include` directive.

I had stored my document class in the same directory as the `.fla` file, because it's a class specific to the project. The document class contained the `include` directive, but the class that was *actually* using the extended `Array` functions was within `lib/libname`.

Moving the `include` directive to the `.as` file that required the extended features allowed the `include` directive to be called relative to the location of the calling class, which allowed me to use `include "../inc/array.as";` because the `.as` file was within `lib/libname/utils/ClassName.as`.

So the answer to the issue is that the include path is relative to the location of the **calling** script, *not* the project. This means that any script within the library can include features from the library without issue, as the structure will be preserved.